# adding Focus In and Focus out events in Q Line Edit PYQT

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I want to set FocusIn and Focusout events on QLine Edit widget but not able to do so. i know that i am very near to the solution but not able to get the exact solution. my code:-

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
url = QtGui.QLineEdit("Please enter URL", w)
url.setFixedWidth(800)
url.move(500,0)
url.focusInEvent(QFocusEvent)

if url.gotFocus():
 print "got focus"
elif url.lostFocus():
 print "lost focus"
```

please help me in debugging the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably check the documentation for the [`focusInEvent`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#focusInEvent) method

> This event handler can be reimplemented in a subclass to receive
>   keyboard focus events (focus received) for the widget.

It's meant to be overridden in a subclass.  You don't call it directly, the event system calls it automatically when the *focusIn* event happens.  You would need to do something like this.

```
class MyLineEdit(QtGui.QLineEdit):

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        print 'focus in event'
        # do custom stuff
        super(MyLineEdit, self).focusInEvent(event)
```

`gotFocus` and `lostFocus` aren't even actual methods.